# Azure Logic App - How Can We Control or Manage Updates

Tags: azure

It looks like from time to time Microsoft update their logic apps. But the problem is these updates were applied automatically without any email notifications and our solution which is currently live will suddenly not run because of these updates. Is there a way to manage these updates in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Logic App is still in Preview (read Beta) and breaking changes are to be expected.  I'd suggest you subscribe to the Logic App [team blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/) and [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbJQweD96Y7n-ebKpdLDJww) where the team host monthly meetings.

Comment: I guess for now what we can do is to monitor their releases and check our logic apps if the release affects them. Thanks!